# preg_replace(): Как убрать всё после вопросительного знака?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

```
preg_replace('/\?(.*?)/i', '', 'http://site.ru/?lang=eng&type=set');
```

Как убрать всё, что после знака "**?**" ? В данном случае удаляется только сам знак, а надо, чтобы всё, что после него...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно через explode =).

```
$url = 'http://site.ru/?lang=eng&type=set';  
$a = explode('?', $url);  
$a = $a[0];  
echo $a;
```

Comment: @Node_pro, спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Рассмотрю Ваше выражение, чтобы Вы поняли почему это не работает.

```
/\?(.*?)/i
```

`1.`(Главная ошибка) После воспитательного знака стоит минимальная квантификация.

```
(.*?)
```

Минимальный квантификатор работает следующим образом: он старается захватить минимальное значение, и расширяется вправо только если это необходимо для общего совпадения. В Вашем случае после него ничего не стоит, а значит он просто совпадает с «ничем» всегда.
То есть это выражение всегда будет находить только первый знак вопроса.
`2.`(Излишне) Вы используете группирующие скобки для

```
.*?
```

это излишне, так как потом эта группа не используется в выражении замены.
`3.`(Совсем не надо) Вы используете флаг игнора регистра символов, но ни одного символа в выражении нет.
`4.`(Как исправить) Чтобы исправить ошибку надо заменить минимальную квантификацию на максимальную. Такой квантификатор сначала захватывает максимально возможный текст, и уменьшает его размер только если это нужно для общего совпадения, но если после него ничего не должно совпасть, то значит он захватит весь текст до конца строки. То есть такое

```
/\?.*/
```

регулярное выражение успешно справиться с поставленной задачей.

Comment: @ReinRaus, ого, спасибо Вам большое, за такое объяснение!

Answer (score 0):

Еще есть функция parse_url, по смыслу она должна больше подойти.

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = 'Hello, world!?123123123';
echo stristr($var,'?',true); // >= php ver 5.3
```

выведет Hello, world!

[php stristr](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.stristr.php)

Comment: Следует добавить описание к происходящему

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в ваш ответ описание кода, чтобы пользователям было легче его понять. Для редактирования ответа, нажмите [Edit]. Так же можете ознакомиться с советами о том, [как написать хороший ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). - [Из очереди проверок](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/148417)